# passing controller json result to view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I need to simply passed the json data which is created in controller to view 
my codes are as follow:

My Model: **Machines.cs**
In my model I get the dates as a string and parse them to datetime. Parsing operation is successful when I hit a breakpoint there,I see the result.

```
   public class Machines
{
    [Key]
    public int AutoKey;
    public string MachineGroup;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public int Duration;
    public List<Machines> SqlAccessParameter(string startDate,string endDate)
    {
        DateTime sDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
        DateTime eDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
        string connstr = "Data Source=USER-BILGISAYAR;Initial Catalog=Report;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("DateRange", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SP_startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = sDate;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SP_endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = eDate;

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dSet);

        myConnection.Close();

        List<Machines> machinePost = new List<Machines>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Machines mac = new Machines();
            mac.AutoKey = (int)row["AUTOKEY"];
            mac.MachineGroup = (string)row["MACHINEGROUP"];
            mac.Duration = (int)row["DURATION"];
            mac.StartDate = (DateTime)row["STARTTIME"];
            mac.EndDate = (DateTime)row["ENDTIME"];
            machinePost.Add(mac);
        }
        return machinePost;
    }
}
```

}

My controller: **MachinesController.cs**

```
         public ActionResult MachineParameter()
       {
        Machines model = new Machines();
        return View("Index",model);
       }
```

My View:Index
In my view I try to draw a chart according to data that is in the user specified date range but it is not successful.

```
@model DenemeReport.Models.Machines
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <head>
<title>Intro</title>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 </head>
   <div>

   Start Date:  <input type="text" id="start" name="start" />

   End Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end" />

   </div>
   <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="CallAjaxFunction()" />

 <body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>

    function CallAjaxFunction() {

        var sDate = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var eDate = document.getElementById('end').value;

        $.ajax
             ({
                 url: "@Url.Action("MachineParameter","Machines")",
                 data: { startDate: sDate, endDate: eDate },
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function () {
                     alert(sDate);
                     $("#chart").kendoChart
                 ({
                     theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                     title: {
                         text: "Pie Chart Test"
                     },
                     legend: {
                         position: "bottom",
                     },

                     dataSource:
                         {
                             transport:
                                 {
                                     read:
                                             {
                                                 url: "@Url.Action("MachineParameter", "Machines")",
                                                 dataType: "json",
                                                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                                             }
                                 }
                         },

                     seriesDefaults: {
                         labels: {
                             visible: true,
                             format: "{0}"
                         }
                     },

                     series: [{
                         type: "pie",
                         field: "Duration",
                         categoryField: "MachineGroup"
                     }],

                     tooltip: {
                         visible: true,
                         format: "{0}"
                     }
                 });
                 }

             });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access it via your Model or make an AJAX request to the `Parameter` action in your controller. I have rewrote your Parameter Action to return the View and use the MachinesSql as the model:

```
public ActionResult Parameter()
{
   MachinesSql model = new MachinesSql();

   return View("YourViewName", model);
}
```

Then in your view you could do:

```
@Model MachinesSql

foreach(var m in @Model.SqlAccessParameter(startDate, endDate)) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.DataValue);
}
```

**Edit: Showing how to achieve via an AJAX Call**

```
function CallAjaxFunction() {
     var sDate = document.getElementById('start');
     var eDate = document.getElementById('end');

     $.ajax{({
         url: '@Url.Action("Parameter")',
         data: { startDate: sDate, endDate: eDate },
         type: "POST",
         success: function(content) { 
            alert(content);
         }
     }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darren Davies, but I need json data.How can I achieve this in view?

Comment: @pln - make an AJAX Request to the Parameter controller and use the result that will be passed down as JSON.

Comment: In view @Model.SqlAccessParameter(startDate, endDate) , startDate and endDate must be taken from users and this part is giving error

Comment: @pln - I have updated my post to demonstrate how you can get start and enddate values and pass them to an AJAX call.  Note you will need jquery to use the $.ajax method.

Comment: @Model.SqlAccessParameter(startDate, endDate) part is still giving error :There is no applicable variable or member 'startDate' and 'endDate'

Comment: @pln - they are defined in the javascript function, sDate and eDate.  Use Fiddler2 to ensure they are getting passed to the server.

Comment: Thanks @Darren Davies but startDate and endDate are not getting passed to server,I could not see the values of them in Fiddler.

Comment: @pln - in your CallAjaxFunction() { } do alert(sDate); alert(eDate); and see if they return a value.

Comment: I get the value of sDate and eDate in CallAjaxFunction{} but I cannot get the data which is in this date range. What am I doing wrong? I update my CallAjaxFunction above.

Comment: @pln - ah, you cannot send up a DateTime object like that.  Try changing the startDate and endDate in the SqlAccessParameter method to string not DateTime.  Then parse the strings to DateTimes in the SqlAccessParameter method.  Make sense?

Comment: Is it like that?      public List<Machines> SqlAccessParameter(string startDate,string endDate)
        {
            DateTime sDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
            DateTime eDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

Comment: @pln - yes test it to see if it can parse the date correctly.

Comment: It can parse the date correctly but still I cannot get the data in this date range.

Comment: I added the latest version of my program above.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life :) I fixed the problem, it was my own mistake.Thank you again!

Comment: Darren I have a one last question for you. Why could't I send up DateTime parameters (startDate and endDate) as (datetime startDate,datetime endDate) in SqlAccessParameter method?

Comment: @pln - because JavaScript doesn't know how to convert it to a C# DateTime object.  You could use the `Date.UTC` function and accept a UTC Date in your SqlAccessParameter method however I usually send string content to the server and parse it server side.